# Matplotlib does not show the graph in the def main

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

My code is still running normally but matplotlib's graph is not showing. Because of the c_v coherence score, def main must be used, but using def main does not show the graphs of matplotlib and pyLDAvis. I don't know what the error is, or is there a problem with my previous code

```
def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('ClearFunc_textana.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
    df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='like_count', ascending=False)
    df_top_10000 = df_sorted.iloc[:10000]

    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    docs = df_top_10000['processed_content'].apply(lambda x: [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(x.lower()) if
                   word.isalpha() and word not in stop_words])

    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(docs)
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]

    lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=10, random_state=100, update_every=1, chunksize=100, passes=10, alpha='auto', per_word_topics=True)

    for idx, topic in lda_model.print_topics(-1):
        print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(idx, topic))
        print('\n')

    cm = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, corpus=corpus, coherence='c_v', texts=docs)
    coherence = cm.get_coherence()
    print('Coherence score:', coherence)
    print('\nPerplexity: ', lda_model.log_perplexity(corpus))

    def model_coherence_generator(corpus, dictionary, data, start_topic, end_topic, step, passes, workers):
        models = []
        coherence_scores = []
        for num in tqdm(range(start_topic, end_topic + 1, step)):
            ldamodel = LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num, passes=passes, workers=workers)
            cv_coherence_model = CoherenceModel(model=ldamodel, corpus=corpus, coherence='c_v', texts=data)
            score = cv_coherence_model.get_coherence()

            coherence_scores.append(score)
            models.append(ldamodel)
        return models, coherence_scores

        lda_models, coherence_scores = model_coherence_generator(corpus, dictionary, docs, start_topic=2, end_topic=40, step=2, passes=10, workers=10)

        x_ax = range(2, 41, 2)
        y_ax = coherence_scores
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
        plt.plot(x_ax, y_ax, c='r')
        plt.axhline(y=0.354, c='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
        plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'white'
        plt.title('Number of Topics vs Coherence Score')
        xl = plt.xlabel('Number of Topics')
        yl = plt.ylabel('Coherence Score')
        plt.savefig("figure.png")
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have searched many related keywords, or written matplotlib back end at the top of the page but still not solved the problem

Comment: What IDE are you using? Do the figures show up when you use matplotlib in a separate script?

Comment: I use pycharm. I tried and it also doesn't work in a separate script too. But the original code I learned works, but when I use it, it doesn't. Not sure if it's due to platform differences, original code used on jupyterbooks

Comment: I mean, if you create a new script that just makes a plot and shows it (e.g. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.figure(); plt.show()`), does anything show up or are you generally having issues with matplotlib figures showing up in pycharm?

Comment: sorry, I'm not very familiar as I just started studying this semester. I can still use matplotlib in other scipts, but in this scripts, I need to run it in a function, and it has many variables associated so I can't separate matplotlib from running separately.

Comment: That's fine, I just needed you to confirm that you can create and show matplotlib plots in pycharm on your machine.

Comment: Now, looking closer, I see you never actually call the `model_coherence_generator` function, which should explain why you don't see any plots.

Comment: I followed the original code, they didn't call it out either so I thought it was normal. Can you clarify for me what to call it out in this case pls

Comment: i have searched with many website tutorials, they are all directly written like this, so i am not very clear how it is different

Comment: Assuming your code is exactly as you pasted it, you have an indentation issue. Did you mean to have the line with `lda_models, coherence_scores = model_coherence_generator(...)` and below indented one level to the left? As is, you have a return statement beforehand and you never actually use the `model_coherence_generator` function.

Comment: I do not really understand. does that mean I have to put the lines below the return line indented one level to the right? but it will give an error as unexpected indent, and if i put it further to the left than it is now, the system will report an error that module cannot callable

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have an indentation issue. As you've posted it, the plotting happens inside the `model_coherence_generator` function, which is never called (though even if it were called, no plot would be created since there is a `return` before the plotting code). I think your issue will be fixed if you move the indentation one level back after the `return` line of the `model_coherence_generator` function, as shown below.

```py
def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('ClearFunc_textana.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
    df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='like_count', ascending=False)
    df_top_10000 = df_sorted.iloc[:10000]

    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    docs = df_top_10000['processed_content'].apply(lambda x: [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize(x.lower()) if
                   word.isalpha() and word not in stop_words])

    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(docs)
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in docs]

    lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=10, random_state=100, update_every=1, chunksize=100, passes=10, alpha='auto', per_word_topics=True)

    for idx, topic in lda_model.print_topics(-1):
        print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(idx, topic))
        print('\n')

    cm = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, corpus=corpus, coherence='c_v', texts=docs)
    coherence = cm.get_coherence()
    print('Coherence score:', coherence)
    print('\nPerplexity: ', lda_model.log_perplexity(corpus))

    def model_coherence_generator(corpus, dictionary, data, start_topic, end_topic, step, passes, workers):
        models = []
        coherence_scores = []
        for num in tqdm(range(start_topic, end_topic + 1, step)):
            ldamodel = LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num, passes=passes, workers=workers)
            cv_coherence_model = CoherenceModel(model=ldamodel, corpus=corpus, coherence='c_v', texts=data)
            score = cv_coherence_model.get_coherence()

            coherence_scores.append(score)
            models.append(ldamodel)
        return models, coherence_scores

    lda_models, coherence_scores = model_coherence_generator(corpus, dictionary, docs, start_topic=2, end_topic=40, step=2, passes=10, workers=10)

    x_ax = range(2, 41, 2)
    y_ax = coherence_scores
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(x_ax, y_ax, c='r')
    plt.axhline(y=0.354, c='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
    plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'white'
    plt.title('Number of Topics vs Coherence Score')
    xl = plt.xlabel('Number of Topics')
    yl = plt.ylabel('Coherence Score')
    plt.savefig("figure.png")
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: sorry for just now rep, but i ran as you wrote and got error module object is not callable

Comment: Where did you get the error?